# Convert from require to import es6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to use these 3 lines with `import` instead..

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {promisify} = require("util");
const pipeline = promisify(require("stream").pipeline);
```

First 2 lines I think are as simple as:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import {promisify} from 'util';
```

How the hell do I convert the 3rd line though?! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it up.

```
import stream from 'stream';
const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);
```